# What to set PICOHTTPS_CA_ROOT_CERT in picohttps example in RPi Pico C - SDK

Tags: arduino, web-server, pi-pico, security, pi-pico-w

I'm trying to make a request to an ip using RPi pico w, using the picohttps example provided in here.

Now for that we have 3 needed parameters in picohttps.h file - SSID, SSID_Password, PICOHTTPS_CA_ROOT_CERT. I've filled first two, but couldn't understand what to write here. I know about RootCA cert little bit, but what part to write here? Whole certificate?

Any other working example for http request using pico c-sdk would be great also.

https://github.com/marceloalcocer/picohttps

Here(pichohttps.h) - ???

```
#define PICOHTTPS_CA_ROOT_CERT                          \
{                                                       \
    0x03, 0x3a, 0xf1, 0xe6, 0xa7, 0x11, 0xa9, 0xa0,     \
    0xbb, 0x28, 0x64, 0xb1, 0x1d, 0x09, 0xfa, 0xe5      \
}
```

I've attached my code as of now.

picohttps.h

```
/* Pico HTTPS request example *************************************************
 *                                                                            *
 *  An HTTPS client example for the Raspberry Pi Pico W                       *
 *                                                                            *
 *  A simple yet complete example C application which sends a single request  *
 *  to a web server over HTTPS and reads the resulting response.              *
 *                                                                            *
 ******************************************************************************/

#ifndef PICOHTTPS_H
#define PICOHTTPS_H



/* Options ********************************************************************/

// Wireless region
//
//  `country` argument to cyw43_arch_init_with_country().
//
//  For best performance, set to local region.
//
//  https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/pico-sdk/networking.html#CYW43_COUNTRY_
//
#define PICOHTTPS_INIT_CYW43_COUNTRY                CYW43_COUNTRY_INDIA

// Wireless network SSID
#define PICOHTTPS_WIFI_SSID                         "mywifi"

// Wireless network connection timeout
//
//  `timeout` argument to cyw43_arch_wifi_connect_timeout_ms().
//
//  https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/pico-sdk/networking.html
//
#define PICOHTTPS_WIFI_TIMEOUT                      20000           // ms

// Wireless network password
//
//  N.b. _Strongly_ recommend setting this from the environment rather than
//  here. Environment values will have greater precedence. See CMakeLists.txt.
//
// #ifndef PICOHTTPS_WIFI_PASSWORD
#define PICOHTTPS_WIFI_PASSWORD                     "password"
// #endif // PICOHTTPS_WIFI_PASSWORD

// HTTP server hostname
#define PICOHTTPS_HOSTNAME                          "example.edu"

// DNS response polling interval
//
//  Interval with which to poll for responses to DNS queries.
//
#define PICOHTTPS_RESOLVE_POLL_INTERVAL             100             // ms

// Certificate authority root certificate
//
//  CA root certificate used to sign the HTTP server's certificate (DER
//  format, char array representation).
//
//  This is most readily obtained via inspection of the server's certificate
//  chain, e.g. in a browser.
//
// #define PICOHTTPS_CA_ROOT_CERT                          
// {                                                       
//     0x03, 0x3a, 0xf1, 0xe6, 0xa7, 0x11, 0xa9, 0xa0,     
//     0xbb, 0x28, 0x64, 0xb1, 0x1d, 0x09, 0xfa, 0xe5      

// }

#define PICOHTTPS_CA_ROOT_CERT                          \
{                                                       \
    0x03, 0x3a, 0xf1, 0xe6, 0xa7, 0x11, 0xa9, 0xa0,     \
    0xbb, 0x28, 0x64, 0xb1, 0x1d, 0x09, 0xfa, 0xe5      \
}

// 07:5B:CE:F3:06:89:C8:AD:
// DF:13:E5:1A:F4:AF:E1:87

// 03:3A:F1:E6:A7:11:A9:A0:
// BB:28:64:B1:1D:09:FA:E5




// TCP + TLS connection establishment polling interval
//
//  Interval with which to poll for establishment of TCP + TLS connection
//
#define PICOHTTPS_ALTCP_CONNECT_POLL_INTERVAL       100             // ms

// TCP + TLS idle connection polling interval
//
//  Interval with which to poll application (i.e. call registered polling
//  callback function) when TCP + TLS connection is idle.
//
//  The callback function should be registered with altcp_poll(). The polling
//  interval is given in units of 'coarse grain timer shots'; one shot
//  corresponds to approximately 500 ms.
//
//  https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__altcp.html
//
#define PICOHTTPS_ALTCP_IDLE_POLL_INTERVAL          2               // shots

// HTTP request
//
//  Plain-text HTTP request to send to server
//
#define PICOHTTPS_REQUEST                   \
    "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"                    \
    "Host: " PICOHTTPS_HOSTNAME "\r\n"      \
    "\r\n"


// HTTP response polling interval
//
//  Interval with which to poll for HTTP response from server.
//
#define PICOHTTPS_HTTP_RESPONSE_POLL_INTERVAL       100             // ms



/* Macros *********************************************************************/

// Array length
#define LEN(array) (sizeof array)/(sizeof array[0])



/* Data structures ************************************************************/

// lwIP errors
//
//  typedef here to make source of error code more explicit
//
typedef err_t lwip_err_t;

// TCP connection callback argument
//
//  All callbacks associated with lwIP TCP (+ TLS) connections can be passed a
//  common argument. This is intended to allow application state to be accessed
//  from within the callback context. The argument should be registered with
//  altcp_arg().
//
//  The following structure is used for this argument in order to supply all
//  the relevant application state required by the various callbacks.
//
//  https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__altcp.html
//
struct altcp_callback_arg{

    // TCP + TLS connection configurtaion
    //
    //  Memory allocated to the connection configuration structure needs to be
    //  freed (with altcp_tls_free_config) in the connection error callback
    //  (callback_altcp_err).
    //
    //  https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__altcp.html
    //  https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__altcp__tls.html
    //
    struct altcp_tls_config* config;

    // TCP + TLS connection state
    //
    //  Successful establishment of a connection needs to be signaled to the
    //  application from the connection connect callback
    //  (callback_altcp_connect).
    //
    //  https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__altcp.html
    //
    bool connected;

    // Data reception acknowledgement
    //
    //  The amount of data acknowledged as received by the server needs to be
    //  communicated to the application from the connection sent callback
    //  (callback_altcp_sent) for validatation of successful transmission.
    //
    u16_t acknowledged;

};



/* Functions ******************************************************************/

// Initialise standard I/O over USB
//
//  @return         `true` on success
//
bool init_stdio(void);

// Initialise Pico W wireless hardware
//
//  @return         `true` on success
//
bool init_cyw43(void);

// Connect to wireless network
//
//  @return         `true` on success
//
bool connect_to_network(void);

// Resolve hostname
//
//  @param ipaddr   Pointer to an `ip_addr_t` where the resolved IP address
//                  should be stored.
//
//  @return         `true` on success
//
bool resolve_hostname(ip_addr_t* ipaddr);

// Free TCP + TLS protocol control block
//
//  Memory allocated for a protocol control block (with altcp_tls_new) needs to
//  be freed (with altcp_close).
//
//  @param pcb      Pointer to a `altcp_pcb` structure to be freed
//
void altcp_free_pcb(struct altcp_pcb* pcb);

// Free TCP + TLS connection configuration
//
//  Memory allocated for TCP + TLS connection configuration (with
//  altcp_tls_create_config_client) needs to be freed (with
//  altcp_tls_free_config).
//
//  @param config   Pointer to a `altcp_tls_config` structure to be freed
//
void altcp_free_config(struct altcp_tls_config* config);

// Free TCP + TLS connection callback argument
//
//  The common argument passed to lwIP connection callbacks must remain in
//  scope for the duration of all callback contexts (i.e. connection lifetime).
//  As such, it cannot be declared with function scope when registering the
//  callback, but rather should be allocated on the heap. This implies the
//  allocated memory must be freed on connection close.
//
//  @param arg      Pointer to a `altcp_callback_arg` structure to be freed
//
void altcp_free_arg(struct altcp_callback_arg* arg);

// Establish TCP + TLS connection with server
//
//  @param ipaddr   Pointer to an `ip_addr_t` containing the server's IP
//                  address
//  @param pcb      Double pointer to a `altcp_pcb` structure where the
//                  protocol control block for the established connection
//                  should be stored.
//
//  @return         `true` on success
//
bool connect_to_host(ip_addr_t* ipaddr, struct altcp_pcb** pcb);

// Send HTTP request
//
//  @param pcb      Pointer to a `altcp_pcb` structure containing the TCP + TLS
//                  connection PCB to the server.
//
//  @return         `true` on success
//
bool send_request(struct altcp_pcb* pcb);

// DNS response callback
//
//  Callback function fired on DNS query response.
//
//  Registered with dns_gethostbyname().
//
//  https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__dns.html
//
void callback_gethostbyname(
    const char* name,
    const ip_addr_t* resolved,
    void* ipaddr
);

// TCP + TLS connection error callback
//
//  Callback function fired on TCP + TLS connection fatal error.
//
//  Registered with altcp_err().
//
//  https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__altcp.html
//
void callback_altcp_err(void* arg, lwip_err_t err);

// TCP + TLS connection idle callback
//
//  Callback function fired on idle TCP + TLS connection.
//
//  Registered with altcp_err().
//
//  https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__altcp.html
//
lwip_err_t callback_altcp_poll(void* arg, struct altcp_pcb* pcb);

// TCP + TLS data acknowledgement callback
//
//  Callback function fired on acknowledgement of data reception by server over
//  a TCP + TLS connection.
//
//  Registered with altcp_sent().
//
//  https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__altcp.html
//
lwip_err_t callback_altcp_sent(void* arg, struct altcp_pcb* pcb, u16_t len);

// TCP + TLS data reception callback
//
//  Callback function fired on reception of data from server over a TCP +
//  TLS connection.
//
//  Registered with altcp_recv().
//
//  https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__altcp.html
//
lwip_err_t callback_altcp_recv(
    void* arg,
    struct altcp_pcb* pcb,
    struct pbuf* buf,
    lwip_err_t err
);

// TCP + TLS connection establishment callback
//
//  Callback function fired on successful establishment of TCP + TLS connection.
//
//  Registered with altcp_connect().
//
//  https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__altcp.html
//
lwip_err_t callback_altcp_connect(
    void* arg,
    struct altcp_pcb* pcb,
    lwip_err_t err
);

#endif //PICOHTTPS_H
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment:

```
//  CA root certificate used to sign the HTTP server's certificate (DER
//  format, char array representation).
```

is saying that you need to find the Root CA certificate that was used to sign the chain of certificates that signed the certificate used by the HTTPS server.

For `raspberrypi.stackexchange.com`, this is the certificate called "ISRG Root X2" highlighted in grey below.

[image]

This certificate needs to be in DER (binary) format. Unfortunately, Chrome doesn't have an option to export the certificate in DER format.  After exporting from Chrome I had to use the following OPENssl command to convert the certificate to DER/binary:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in "ISRG Root X2" -out "ISRG Root X2.der"
```

Then use `xxd -i` to convert the binary DER file to character array format and paste the character array into your header file.

```
xxd -i ISRG\ Root\ X2.der 
unsigned char ISRG_Root_X2_der[] = {
  0x30, 0x82, 0x02, 0x1b, 0x30, 0x82, 0x01, 0xa1, 0xa0, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01,
  0x02, 0x02, 0x10, 0x41, 0xd2, 0x9d, 0xd1, 0x72, 0xea, 0xee, 0xa7, 0x80,
  0xc1, 0x2c, 0x6c, 0xe9, 0x2f, 0x87, 0x52, 0x30, 0x0a, 0x06, 0x08, 0x2a,
  0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x04, 0x03, 0x03, 0x30, 0x4f, 0x31, 0x0b, 0x30,
  0x09, 0x06, 0x03, 0x55, 0x04, 0x06, 0x13, 0x02, 0x55, 0x53, 0x31, 0x29,
  0x30, 0x27, 0x06, 0x03, 0x55, 0x04, 0x0a, 0x13, 0x20, 0x49, 0x6e, 0x74,
  0x65, 0x72, 0x6e, 0x65, 0x74, 0x20, 0x53, 0x65, 0x63, 0x75, 0x72, 0x69,
  0x74, 0x79, 0x20, 0x52, 0x65, 0x73, 0x65, 0x61, 0x72, 0x63, 0x68, 0x20,
  0x47, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x70, 0x31, 0x15, 0x30, 0x13, 0x06, 0x03, 0x55,
  0x04, 0x03, 0x13, 0x0c, 0x49, 0x53, 0x52, 0x47, 0x20, 0x52, 0x6f, 0x6f,
  0x74, 0x20, 0x58, 0x32, 0x30, 0x1e, 0x17, 0x0d, 0x32, 0x30, 0x30, 0x39,
  0x30, 0x34, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x5a, 0x17, 0x0d, 0x34,
  0x30, 0x30, 0x39, 0x31, 0x37, 0x31, 0x36, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x5a,
  0x30, 0x4f, 0x31, 0x0b, 0x30, 0x09, 0x06, 0x03, 0x55, 0x04, 0x06, 0x13,
  0x02, 0x55, 0x53, 0x31, 0x29, 0x30, 0x27, 0x06, 0x03, 0x55, 0x04, 0x0a,
  0x13, 0x20, 0x49, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x6e, 0x65, 0x74, 0x20, 0x53,
  0x65, 0x63, 0x75, 0x72, 0x69, 0x74, 0x79, 0x20, 0x52, 0x65, 0x73, 0x65,
  0x61, 0x72, 0x63, 0x68, 0x20, 0x47, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x70, 0x31, 0x15,
  0x30, 0x13, 0x06, 0x03, 0x55, 0x04, 0x03, 0x13, 0x0c, 0x49, 0x53, 0x52,
  0x47, 0x20, 0x52, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x20, 0x58, 0x32, 0x30, 0x76, 0x30,
  0x10, 0x06, 0x07, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0xce, 0x3d, 0x02, 0x01, 0x06, 0x05,
  0x2b, 0x81, 0x04, 0x00, 0x22, 0x03, 0x62, 0x00, 0x04, 0xcd, 0x9b, 0xd5,
  0x9f, 0x80, 0x83, 0x0a, 0xec, 0x09, 0x4a, 0xf3, 0x16, 0x4a, 0x3e, 0x5c,
  0xcf, 0x77, 0xac, 0xde, 0x67, 0x05, 0x0d, 0x1d, 0x07, 0xb6, 0xdc, 0x16,
  0xfb, 0x5a, 0x8b, 0x14, 0xdb, 0xe2, 0x71, 0x60, 0xc4, 0xba, 0x45, 0x95,
  0x11, 0x89, 0x8e, 0xea, 0x06, 0xdf, 0xf7, 0x2a, 0x16, 0x1c, 0xa4, 0xb9,
  0xc5, 0xc5, 0x32, 0xe0, 0x03, 0xe0, 0x1e, 0x82, 0x18, 0x38, 0x8b, 0xd7,
  0x45, 0xd8, 0x0a, 0x6a, 0x6e, 0xe6, 0x00, 0x77, 0xfb, 0x02, 0x51, 0x7d,
  0x22, 0xd8, 0x0a, 0x6e, 0x9a, 0x5b, 0x77, 0xdf, 0xf0, 0xfa, 0x41, 0xec,
  0x39, 0xdc, 0x75, 0xca, 0x68, 0x07, 0x0c, 0x1f, 0xea, 0xa3, 0x42, 0x30,
  0x40, 0x30, 0x0e, 0x06, 0x03, 0x55, 0x1d, 0x0f, 0x01, 0x01, 0xff, 0x04,
  0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x06, 0x30, 0x0f, 0x06, 0x03, 0x55, 0x1d, 0x13,
  0x01, 0x01, 0xff, 0x04, 0x05, 0x30, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0xff, 0x30, 0x1d,
  0x06, 0x03, 0x55, 0x1d, 0x0e, 0x04, 0x16, 0x04, 0x14, 0x7c, 0x42, 0x96,
  0xae, 0xde, 0x4b, 0x48, 0x3b, 0xfa, 0x92, 0xf8, 0x9e, 0x8c, 0xcf, 0x6d,
  0x8b, 0xa9, 0x72, 0x37, 0x95, 0x30, 0x0a, 0x06, 0x08, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48,
  0xce, 0x3d, 0x04, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x68, 0x00, 0x30, 0x65, 0x02, 0x30,
  0x7b, 0x79, 0x4e, 0x46, 0x50, 0x84, 0xc2, 0x44, 0x87, 0x46, 0x1b, 0x45,
  0x70, 0xff, 0x58, 0x99, 0xde, 0xf4, 0xfd, 0xa4, 0xd2, 0x55, 0xa6, 0x20,
  0x2d, 0x74, 0xd6, 0x34, 0xbc, 0x41, 0xa3, 0x50, 0x5f, 0x01, 0x27, 0x56,
  0xb4, 0xbe, 0x27, 0x75, 0x06, 0xaf, 0x12, 0x2e, 0x75, 0x98, 0x8d, 0xfc,
  0x02, 0x31, 0x00, 0x8b, 0xf5, 0x77, 0x6c, 0xd4, 0xc8, 0x65, 0xaa, 0xe0,
  0x0b, 0x2c, 0xee, 0x14, 0x9d, 0x27, 0x37, 0xa4, 0xf9, 0x53, 0xa5, 0x51,
  0xe4, 0x29, 0x83, 0xd7, 0xf8, 0x90, 0x31, 0x5b, 0x42, 0x9f, 0x0a, 0xf5,
  0xfe, 0xae, 0x00, 0x68, 0xe7, 0x8c, 0x49, 0x0f, 0xb6, 0x6f, 0x5b, 0x5b,
  0x15, 0xf2, 0xe7
};
unsigned int ISRG_Root_X2_der_len = 543;
```

**Option 2:**

According to [this article](https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/hardware/16268-master-the-pico-wifi-simplest-https-client.html?start=2), you may be able to specify `NULL` for the certificate.

> **A Simple TLS Client**
>
> A good starting point in getting to grips with
> mbedtls is to convert the simplest HTTP client program given in
> Chapter 2 to HTTPS. The simplicity of this program lets you see where
> the changes have to be made.
>
> What might surprise you is how easy the conversion to HTTPS is. All
> you have to do to the main program is add:
>
> `#include "lwip/altcp_tls.h`"
> and replace the line which constructs the standard TCP PCB:
>
> `struct altcp_pcb *pcb = altcp_new(NULL);`
> by:
>
> `struct altcp_tls_config *tls_config =`
> `altcp_tls_create_config_client(NULL, 0);`
>
> `struct altcp_pcb *pcb = altcp_tls_new(tls_config,`
> `IPADDR_TYPE_ANY);`